# RegEx Matching where input goes onto a new line

Tags: node.js, regex

I have the following RegEx pattern:

```
const test = new RegExp('var _0x((?=\\d+[A-Za-z]+[\\w@]+|[a-zA-Z]+[\\w@]+)[\\w@]{6}) = {(.*?)}/', 'gm');
const res = test.exec(script);
```

I also have the following input string:

```
var _0x48ff10 = {
    "Gxh": function _0x14cba1(_0x248470) {
        return _0x248470();
    }, "Zvp": function _0x79a852(_0x5e72a5, _0xb98ae2) {
        return _0x5e72a5 < _0xb98ae2;
    }, "Zol": function _0x536e02(_0x1c65c3, _0x4116c9) {
        return _0x1c65c3 + _0x4116c9;
    }
};
```

The expected matching text should be:

```
{
    "Gxh": function _0x14cba1(_0x248470) {
        return _0x248470();
    },
    "Zvp": function _0x79a852(_0x5e72a5, _0xb98ae2) {
        return _0x5e72a5 < _0xb98ae2;
    },
    "Zol": function _0x536e02(_0x1c65c3, _0x4116c9) {
        return _0x1c65c3 + _0x4116c9;
    }
};
```

It seems as if my RegEx is breaking because of the line breaks in the input string.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Do you want something like https://regex101.com/r/rlK4WP/1?

Comment: Well, you're Regex doesn't match the variable declaration, not what's in the curly braces.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [dotAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/dotAll) option, and greedy search, i.e.

```
/... ({.*};)/gms
```

```js
const script = `
var _0x48ff10 = {
    "Gxh": function _0x14cba1(_0x248470) {
        return _0x248470();
    }, "Zvp": function _0x79a852(_0x5e72a5, _0xb98ae2) {
        return _0x5e72a5 < _0xb98ae2;
    }, "Zol": function _0x536e02(_0x1c65c3, _0x4116c9) {
        return _0x1c65c3 + _0x4116c9;
    }
};
`;

const test = /var _0x((?=\d+[A-Za-z]+[\w@]+|[a-zA-Z]+[\w@]+)[\w@]{6}) = ({.*};)/gms;
const res = test.exec(script);
console.log(res[2]);
```